# ActionScript sending asynchronously data to PHP file

Tags: php, actionscript-3, asynchronous

I've to send 300 bitmap datas to a PHP file which saves them as PNGs. I can't just add an `addEventListener` and `Event.COMPLETE`. I'm parsing and creating those bitmap datas in some loops and when a bitmap got created, it sends it to the PHP file. The problem is that it works fine for the first 130+/- images but then I keep getting this error:

> Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error

Is there a way to send the data asynchronously? Cause I think the PHP file can't handle so many requests all at once.

Here's the code:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import com.*;

var loadFurni = new Object();
var loaderID = 0;
var furniName = "tv_luxus";
var furniSwf = "swf/"+furniName+".swf";

loadFurni[loaderID] = new Loader();
var swfRequest = new URLRequest(furniSwf);

loadFurni[loaderID].load(swfRequest);
loadFurni[loaderID].contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);


function onLoaded(event:Event){

    var getAssetXML = event.target.applicationDomain.getDefinition(furniName+"_"+furniName+"_assets");
    getAssetXML = new getAssetXML;
    var assets = new XML(getAssetXML);
    var getVisualXML = event.target.applicationDomain.getDefinition(furniName+"_"+furniName+"_visualization");
    getVisualXML = new getVisualXML;
    var visualization = new XML(getVisualXML);

    var colorsStr = "";
    var colors = colorsStr.split(",");

    //possible sizes
    var furniSizes = new Array(32, 64);

    for each(var furniSize in furniSizes){

        var furniBgWidth;
        var furniBgHeight;
        var furniBg:Bitmap;

        var furniBgX = 0;
        var furniBgY = 0;

        var visualizationID;
        var layerCount;
        var dirs = new Array();
        var blendModes = new Array();
        var alphaModes = new Array();
        var zModes = new Array();

        var paddingBottom = 30;

        //getting the layercount + visualizationID
        for(var l=0; l<visualization.visualization.length(); l++){
            if(visualization.visualization[l].@size == furniSize){
                layerCount = visualization.visualization[l].@layerCount;
                visualizationID = l;
            }
        }


        //now searching the possible directions
        for(var d=0; d<visualization.visualization[visualizationID].directions.direction.length(); d++){
            dirs.push(visualization.visualization[visualizationID].directions.direction[d].@id);
        }

        for each(var dir in dirs){

            var animations = new Array();

            //searching the possible animations
            for(var ta=0; ta<visualization.visualization[visualizationID].animations.animation.length(); ta++){
                animations.push(visualization.visualization[visualizationID].animations.animation[ta].@id);
            }

            //if there's no animation
            if(animations[0] == undefined){ animations = new Array("0"); }

            for each(var animation in animations){
                //getting layersinformations such as blendmodes, zindex and alpha
                var layers = visualization.visualization[visualizationID].layers[0];
                if(layers != undefined && layers.layer[0] != undefined){
                    for each(var layer in layers.layer){
                        blendModes[layer.@id] = (layer.@ink!= undefined) ? layer.@ink : "NORMAL";
                        alphaModes[layer.@id] = (layer.@alpha!= undefined) ? int(layer.@alpha): 255;
                        zModes[layer.@id] = (layer.@z!= undefined) ? int(layer.@z): 0;
                    }
                }


                //zIndex fix. sometimes the zindex is saved in the <direction/>
                for(var zfix=0; zfix<visualization.visualization[visualizationID].directions.direction.length(); zfix++){
                    if(visualization.visualization[visualizationID].directions.direction[zfix].@id == dir){
                        for(var zfixl=0; zfixl<visualization.visualization[visualizationID].directions.direction[zfix].layer.length(); zfixl++){
                            if(visualization.visualization[visualizationID].directions.direction[zfix].layer[zfixl].@z != undefined){
                                zModes[visualization.visualization[visualizationID].directions.direction[zfix].layer[zfixl].@id] = visualization.visualization[visualizationID].directions.direction[zfix].layer[zfixl].@z;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                var frames = new Array();

                //settings the default frames
                if(visualization.visualization[visualizationID].animations != undefined && visualization.visualization[visualizationID].animations.animation != undefined){
                    for each(var animationLayer in visualization.visualization[visualizationID].animations.animation[0].animationLayer){
                        frames[animationLayer.@id] = new Array( );
                        //the problem is, that sometimes there aint no framesequences. so we just add 0 as default.
                        if(animationLayer.frameSequence !=undefined){
                            for each(var sframe in animationLayer.frameSequence.frame){
                                frames[animationLayer.@id].push(sframe.@id);
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            frames[animationLayer.@id].push(0);
                        }
                    }
                }

                //overwriting the stuff with the animation layers
                if(animation>0){
                    for each(animationLayer in visualization.visualization[visualizationID].animations.animation[animation].animationLayer){
                        if(animationLayer.frameSequence !=undefined){
                            if(frames[animationLayer.@id] !=undefined){
                                //clearing the array, so we can overwrite it.
                                frames[animationLayer.@id].splice(0);
                                for each(sframe in animationLayer.frameSequence.frame){
                                    frames[animationLayer.@id].push(sframe.@id);
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                //creating a new array
                                frames[animationLayer.@id].push(0);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                //count lowest framerate
                var lowestFrameRate = 9999;
                for(var low in frames){
                    if(lowestFrameRate > frames[low].length){ 
                        lowestFrameRate = frames[low].length;
                    }
                }

                if(lowestFrameRate == 9999){
                    lowestFrameRate=0;
                }

                //count highest framerate
                var highestFrameRate = 0;
                if(frames[lowestFrameRate] != undefined){
                    for(var high in frames){
                        if(highestFrameRate < frames[high].length){ 
                            highestFrameRate = frames[high].length;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(!highestFrameRate){
                    highestFrameRate=1;
                }


                for(var frame=0; frame<(highestFrameRate); frame++){

                    //trace("[size: "+furniSize+"; dir: "+dir+"; animation: "+animation+"; frame: "+frame+"] {");
                    var furniParts = new Array();
                    var cordHX = 0;
                    var cordLX = 10000;
                    var cordHY = 0;
                    var cordLY = 10000;
                    var cordHYC =0;
                    var actualFrame;

                    for(var i = 0; i<layerCount; i++){
                        if(frames[i] == undefined) actualFrame = 0;
                        else actualFrame = (!frames[i][frame]) ? frames[i][0] : frames[i][frame];

                        for each(var asset in assets.asset){
                            var furniClass = furniName+"_"+furniSize+"_"+String.fromCharCode(97+i)+"_"+dir+"_"+actualFrame;
                            if(asset.@name == furniClass){
                                var flip = false;
                                if(asset.@flipH == "1") {
                                    furniClass = asset.@source;
                                    flip = true;
                                }
                                else if(asset.@source != undefined){
                                    furniClass = asset.@source;
                                }

                                //trace(furniClass);

                                var bmp;

                                if(event.target.applicationDomain.hasDefinition(furniName+"_"+furniClass)){
                                    bmp = event.target.applicationDomain.getDefinition(furniName+"_"+furniClass);
                                    bmp = new bmp;
                                }




                                else  { trace("CONTINUED"); continue; };



                                if(((asset.@x*-1) + (bmp["width"]*1)) > cordHX){
                                    cordHX = (asset.@x*-1) + (bmp["width"]*1);
                                }
                                if(((asset.@x*-1) < cordLX)){
                                    cordLX = (asset.@x*-1);
                                }

                                if(((asset.@y*-1) + (bmp["height"]*1)) > cordHY){
                                    cordHY = (asset.@y*-1) + (bmp["height"]*1);
                                }

                                if(((asset.@y*-1) < cordLY)){
                                    cordLY = (asset.@y*-1);
                                }
                                if(((asset.@y*-1) < cordHYC)){
                                    cordHYC = (asset.@y*-1);
                                }

                                //might not always exist, so we check and set 255 for sure. 
                                if(!alphaModes[i]) alphaModes[i] = 255;

                                var canvas = new Bitmap();
                                canvas.bitmapData = new BitmapData(bmp["width"], bmp["height"], true, 0);

                                //draws the image on the canvas + alpha
                                var matrix = new Matrix();
                                var transforming = new ColorTransform();
                                transforming.alphaMultiplier = (alphaModes[i]/255);
                                canvas.bitmapData.draw(bmp, matrix, transforming);

                                //redraws the image on the canvas + alpha + color
                                if(colors[i]){
                                    var coloring = new ColorTransform();
                                    coloring.color = ("0x"+colors[i]);  //defines colors token by the colors array
                                    coloring.alphaMultiplier = (alphaModes[i]/255);
                                    canvas.bitmapData.draw(bmp, matrix, coloring, BlendMode.MULTIPLY);
                                }

                                if(!zModes[i]){ //fixing zModes
                                    zModes[i] = 0;
                                }

                                //now we'll add all the data into an array(object()). later we'll build it together out of that array
                                furniParts.push({ "daI" : i,"daZ": int(zModes[i]), "daB": blendModes[i], "x" : int(asset.@x), "y" : int(asset.@y), "daC" : canvas });



                            }
                        }



                    }
                    var furniWidth = ((cordHX * 1 - cordLX*1));
                    var furniCenter = Math.abs(int(cordHX)) -  Math.abs(int(cordLX));

                    var furniHeight = ((cordLY*1 - cordHY * 1)*-1);
                    var furniYFix = (cordHYC*-1);

                    //medium 400x400
                    if(furniHeight > (200-paddingBottom) || furniWidth > (200-paddingBottom)){
                        furniBgWidth = 400;
                        furniBgHeight = 400;
                        furniBg = new Bitmap();
                        var bgDataM:bgMedium = new bgMedium(furniBgWidth, furniBgHeight);
                        furniBg.bitmapData = bgDataM;
                    }
                    //large 600x600
                    else if(furniHeight > (400-paddingBottom) || furniWidth > (400-paddingBottom)){
                        furniBgWidth = 600;
                        furniBgHeight = 600;
                        furniBg = new Bitmap();
                        var bgDataL:bgLarge = new bgLarge(furniBgWidth, furniBgHeight);
                        furniBg.bitmapData = bgDataL;

                    }
                    //default, small
                    else {
                        furniBgWidth = 200;
                        furniBgHeight = 200;
                        furniBg = new Bitmap();
                        var bgDataS:bgSmall = new bgSmall(furniBgWidth, furniBgHeight);
                        furniBg.bitmapData = bgDataS;
                    }

                    furniParts.sortOn(["daZ","daI"], [Array.NUMERIC, Array.NUMERIC]);


                    //now let's build it
                    for each(var furniPart in furniParts){
                        //draws canvas on furniBg (?+ blendmode)
                        var finalBlendMode = furniPart.daB;
                        var finalCanvas = furniPart.daC;

                        var posx = (furniBgWidth/2) - (furniCenter/2) - furniPart.x;
                        var posy = furniYFix + furniBgHeight - furniHeight - paddingBottom - furniPart.y;

                        var daMatrix = new Matrix();
                        daMatrix.translate(posx,posy);

                        if(finalBlendMode){
                            if(finalBlendMode == "ADD") furniBg.bitmapData.draw(finalCanvas, daMatrix, null, BlendMode.ADD);
                            else if(finalBlendMode == "NORMAL") furniBg.bitmapData.draw(finalCanvas, daMatrix, null, BlendMode.NORMAL);
                            else if(finalBlendMode == "OVERLAY") furniBg.bitmapData.draw(finalCanvas, daMatrix, null, BlendMode.OVERLAY);
                            else if(finalBlendMode == "ERASE") furniBg.bitmapData.draw(finalCanvas, daMatrix, null, BlendMode.ERASE);
                            else if(finalBlendMode == "ALPHA") furniBg.bitmapData.draw(finalCanvas, daMatrix, null, BlendMode.ALPHA);
                            else if(finalBlendMode == "INVERT") furniBg.bitmapData.draw(finalCanvas, daMatrix, null, BlendMode.INVERT);
                            else if(finalBlendMode == "SUBTRACT") furniBg.bitmapData.draw(finalCanvas, daMatrix, null, BlendMode.SUBTRACT);
                            else if(finalBlendMode == "DIFFERENCE") furniBg.bitmapData.draw(finalCanvas, daMatrix, null, BlendMode.DIFFERENCE);
                            else if(finalBlendMode == "LIGHTEN") furniBg.bitmapData.draw(finalCanvas, daMatrix, null, BlendMode.LIGHTEN);
                            else if(finalBlendMode == "DARKEN") furniBg.bitmapData.draw(finalCanvas, daMatrix, null, BlendMode.DARKEN);
                            else if(finalBlendMode == "SCREEN") furniBg.bitmapData.draw(finalCanvas, daMatrix, null, BlendMode.SCREEN);
                            else if(finalBlendMode == "MULTIPLY") furniBg.bitmapData.draw(finalCanvas, daMatrix, null, BlendMode.MULTIPLY);
                            else if(finalBlendMode == "LAYER") furniBg.bitmapData.draw(finalCanvas, daMatrix, null, BlendMode.LAYER);
                            else furniBg.bitmapData.draw(finalCanvas, daMatrix, null, BlendMode.NORMAL);
                        }
                        else {              
                            furniBg.bitmapData.draw(finalCanvas, daMatrix);
                        }
                    }

                    if(flip){
                        var flipMatrix = new Matrix();
                        flipMatrix.scale(-1,1);
                        flipMatrix.translate(furniBg.width,0);
                        var flipped = new Bitmap();
                        flipped.bitmapData = new BitmapData(furniBg.width, furniBg.height, true, 0);
                        flipped.bitmapData.draw(furniBg, flipMatrix);
                        furniBg = flipped;
                        //trace("dir: "+dir+" - flipped ["+furniSize+"]");
                    }

                    furniBg.x = furniBgX;
                    addChild(furniBg);
                    furniBgX = furniBgX + 200;

                    exportFurni(furniBg, dir, frame, animation, furniSize, furniName);

                    furniBg = null;



                    //trace("}\n\n");

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

function exportFurni(furni, var1, var2, var3, var4,var5){
    var finalFurni = PNGEncoder.encode(furni.bitmapData);
    var reqHeader:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
    var reqURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/furniviewer_flash/export/exporter.php?name="+var5+"&v1="+var1+"&v2="+var2+"&v3="+var3+"&v4="+var4);
    reqURL.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    reqURL.data = finalFurni;
    reqURL.requestHeaders.push(reqHeader);
    var reqLoader = new URLLoader();
/*  reqLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, exported);
    reqLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, notexported);
*/
    reqLoader.load(reqURL);
}
```

Comment: Share some code of your project so we can help you.

Comment: Added it. But it's more of a How-To question cause basically it works perfectly for the first 130 images and then I get the error...

Comment: I was thinking if you could use filereference class to upload images.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html

Answer (score 0):

Listen for that IOError. You might get some more details from it:

```
loadFurni[loaderID].contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
loadFurni[loaderID].contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIoError);

function onIoError( event : IOErrorEvent ) : void {
    // trace/debug the event here...
}
```

HTTPStatusEvent also helps to handle server connections safely and controlled.

I guess there's something in your PHP Script going wrong what raises that error...